# ScatterND Plugin not found while converting onnx into tensorrt model

Tags: onnx, tensorrt, jetson-xavier

Able to convert pytorch model into onnx and validated onnx output with pytorch. it's working fine.
But when I try to convert onnx into tensorrt engine, it fails at onnx parser and return this error.

[TensorRT] ERROR: INVALID_ARGUMENT: getPluginCreator could not find plugin ScatterND version 1

Onnx version : 1.6.0
Tensorrt version : 7.1.3.4

Can anyone please help here, how can I add ScatterND plugin in python and how can I use it ?
Is there any other way to solve this problem ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Same issue for me. Any solutions yet?

Comment: I am also having the same issue. Seems like there is some awareness for this, but little documentation to support the solution. https://github.com/NVIDIA/TensorRT/issues/805

Comment: @sp_713 do you understand how [plugins](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/tensorrt/developer-guide/index.html#extending) work? Aren't they supposed to be the solution to this kind of problems? It would help us also if you shared your model and code. Thank you.